# Running asynchronous functions in series with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to run multiple asynchronous tasks in series using promises. Each task should run right after the previous one finishes. This is simplified example what I have tried:

```
var order = [];
var tasks = [
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(1);
        setTimeout(() => {
            order.push(2)
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(3);
        setTimeout(() => {
            order.push(4)
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(5);
        resolve();
    })
];

tasks.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next), Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    console.log(order); // [ 1, 3, 5 ]
});
setTimeout(() => console.log(order), 200); // [ 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 ]
```

I would expect `order` to be equal `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` in the callback function. However I got those strange results (`[ 1, 3, 5 ]` in `then` callback and `[ 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 ]` in delayed function). What am I missing?

Comment: I'm doing a similar thing in Angular using $q.serial from here: http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/ You could get rid of angular code specific thing and tweak it to fit your needs. You could also take a look at the `waterfall` method from the `async` library: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: The reduce function isn't waiting on the previous promise to resolve before moving on to the next entry in the array, so you're firing all three pushes immediately on your way through the loop. The `setTimeout` delays the resolve(), but it doesn't delay the actions inside the promise

Comment: The moment you write `new Promise(function() {...` that promise callback is running *(you're using arrow functions, but same-same)*. If you want to run them in serial, and not parallell, you can't create the promises in the array like that, you'll need to come up with something different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write something like

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    order.push(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
        order.push(2)
        resolve();
    }, 100);
});
```

it's executed right away, meaning it runs **now**, and resolves in 0.1 seconds.
It doesn't matter that you write it inside an array, the functions are still ran *right now*, and the promises are returned as the values in the array.

In other words, all three promise calls run in parallell, they all run right away, with just milliseconds apart, and resolve at the given timen in the internal timer, from **now**!

If you want to run one promise after the other, they have to somehow be wrapped so they don't run **now**, but whenever they are called, for instance something like

```
var tasks = [
    _ => new Promise(resolve => {
            order.push(1);
            setTimeout(() => {
                order.push(2)
                resolve();
            }, 100);
    }),
    _ => new Promise(resolve => {
            order.push(3);
            setTimeout(() => {
                order.push(4)
                resolve();
            }, 100);
    }),
    _ => new Promise(resolve => {
            order.push(5);
            resolve();
    }),
];
```

*(the underscore is valid ES2015 shorthand for an anonymous arrow function)*

where each array value is an anonymous function that can be called, and when called the promise constructor runs and returns the promise.

To recursively call the functions in serial, a recursive function call is the easiest, where the next function is called when the current is finished etc.

```
(function iterate(i) {
    tasks[i]().then(() => {          // when done
        if (tasks[++i]) iterate(i);  // call the next one
    });
})(0);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4g44r0qk/2/)

---

Edit:

You could also `Array.reduce` the way you're already doing it, now that you have functions that returns promises

```
tasks.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next), Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    // all done, chain is complete !
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You exactly explained what I did wrong. Can you see any benefit using this recursive solution over the one with reduce?

Comment: There just doesn't seem like there is anything to reduce? You have an array of promises, you don't really want to reduce that down to one, you just want to call them sequentially, and the values are in the seperate `order` array, so you don't seem to want to reduce that down either ?

Comment: Solution with reduce works when I change the tasks in array to functions which return promises. With reduce version I can use `then` to add callback which is executed after all tasks finish

Comment: Yes indeed, looks like you're right, the `reduce` works, and it's a neat trick. You have `tasks.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next), Promise.resolve())` where a resolved promise is passed in as an initial value, and then it keeps calling the `next` function when the `cur` function has completed, and the reduced last promise is resolved when the sequential calls are all done. Recursive function calls are often used for this, and you could use `Promise.all` to check that all the promises have resolved, but it would be the same as the `reduce` you already have, so stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the fact that when you're using `setTimeout`, the callbacks (that push `2`, `4` and log `order`) will be executed on **the next iteration of the event loop**, i.e. the next 'tick'. While all other functions (the `Promise` constructors and the `reduce` callback) are being **executed immediately**, i.e. in the current 'tick'.

```
var order = [];
var tasks = [
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(1); // 1. callback executes immediately pushing 1 into order
        setTimeout(() => { // 2. setTimeout executes, pushing the callback into the event queue after 100ms
            order.push(2) // 8. callback executes, pushing 2 into order
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(3); // 3. callback executes immediately pushing 3 into order
        setTimeout(() => { // 4. setTimeout executes, pushing the callback into the event queue after 100ms
            order.push(4) // 9. callback executes, pushing 4 into order
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    }),
    new Promise(resolve => {
        order.push(5); // 5. callback executes immediately pushing 5 into order 
        resolve();
    })
];

console.log(order); // [ 1, 3, 5 ]    

// 6. reduce executes immediately, executes Promise.resolve which logs order and then loops through order and executes the callback everytime
tasks.reduce((cur, next) => cur.then(next), Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    console.log(order); // [ 1, 3, 5 ]
});

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(order); // 10. callback executes and logs order
}, 200); // 7. setTimeout executes, pushing the callback into the event queue after 200ms
```

Only **After** steps 1 through 7 happen, all callbacks that where pushed into the event queue (by `setTimeout`) will be executed, i.e. pushed on the call stack, clearing the event queue and eventually clearing the call stack, after said callbacks execute (steps 8, 9 and 10).

*Note that functions are only popped off the event queue when the call stack is empty.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a promise-less and slightly strange way of doing things, but it seems to work:

```
"use strict";
var order = [];
var i = 0;
function next(){
    if(tasks[++i]) tasks[i]()
}
var tasks = [
    function() {
        order.push(1);
        setTimeout(() => {
            order.push(2)
            next()
        }, 100);
    },
    function() {
        order.push(3);
        setTimeout(() => {
            order.push(4)
            next();
        }, 100);
   },
   function() {
        order.push(5);
        next()
        console.log(order)
    }
];

tasks[0]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every asynchronous function has a synchronous part, the setup leading up to the (synchronous) return of the promise.